# Using Dojo passing value from textbox to alert on click

Tags: textbox, dojo

Using the [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) I am trying to pass the value from textbox to an alert on click. I tried attr to obtain value inside the function helloPressed(), but I am not even able to reset the textbox value when I tried the other way.

I am new to the programming world.

```
function helloPressed() 
{
    var gt =  dojo.attr("htext1","value");
    alert(gt).show();
}

<input dojoType="dijit.form.textbox"  name="name1" widgetId="htext1" 
 dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" intermediateChanges="true" value="hello"  
 trim="true" propercase="true" /></input>
<button dojoType="Button" widgetId="helloButton"
 onClick="helloPressed()">Click !</button>
```

I tried other combinations as well, but no success :(

Answer (score 0):

Add `id="htext1"` among the attributes of your `input` tag; `dojo.attr(somestring, ...)` searches for a DOM node with `id == somestring`, not for one with `widgetId == somestring`.

BTW, use just `alert(gt)` -- that `.show()` is just an error. I recommend using the firefox browser with the firebug plug-in for web development, this way you will see appropriate error messages in firebug's console to help you develop correct HTML, CSS, Javascript, and so on.

Comment: thanks Alex, I tried this
var ht = dojo.byId('htext1');
   ht.dojo.attr("new value");
   alert(gt).show();
and 

var ht = dojo.widged.byId('htext1');
   ht.dojo.attr("newsometext");
  but nothing happens

Comment: sorry , missed the second part. I will try firebug now. Thanks again for helping me

Comment: Did you add 'id="htext1"' to the input tag? That's the crucial part of my answer and I don't see you acknowledging it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like that:

```
var gt = dijit.byId("htext1").attr("value");
alert(gt);
```

`dijit.byId()` retrieves a widget object, and you can call `attr()` on it.

I assume that `alert()` is a standard JavaScript function. If this is correct, you don't need (and actually cannot) use nay properties on it.

Comment: I noticed that if I try to retrieve a widget object, the alert stops responding. If I comment it and instead just pass a variable to the alert it works. I tried your code, but still it doesnot do anything. What if I just want to change the textbox value on click ?

Comment: That's bizarre --- I cannot imagine how working with widget can interfere with alerts. Can you post a minimalistic example somewhere?